# Stack - Broadcast a csv?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I'm creating a spark dataset from a shared store of data as follows:

```
Dataset<Row> item = spark.read().option("delimiter", "|").option("header","true").csv(fName).cache();
```

Is there a way to tell Spark to broadcast item to all nodes, such that no shuffle is needed to use it? I have a bunch of little lookup tables and I'd like to see if broadcasting them helps avoid shuffles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two approaches:

1. `collect()` given Dataset and broadcast it manually. You said that those files are small, so it's possible. But, it will work with UDFs / strong typed operators like `map`, not with standard function.

Example:

```
val items = item.as[MyCaseClass].collect()
val itemsBcV = sparkContext.broadcast(items)

// later, UDF
val funnyUDF = udf ((x : String) => {
    val valueFromBroadcast = itemsBcV.value;
    // processing
});
```

2. **Preferred:** Don't broadcast manually, just in processing add broadcast hint.

First, import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`
For example:

```
someBigTable.join(broadcast(item), "id")
```

in pure SQL syntax it is:

```
item.createOrReplaceTempView("item")
select /*+ BROADCAST(item) */ * from bigTable join item
```

Spark will manage broadcasting this variable and use quicker Broadcast Hash Join instead of Hash Join or Sort Merge Join

Comment: And if it's all happening in SQL?

Comment: @Carbon I've added in the answer